# How to generate struct lowerCamelCase json tag

Tags: go, protocol-buffers

According to Google protoBuf field should be named with underscore ie. `first_name`

an example message will be

```
message Name {
  first_name = 1;
}
```

However, when generating the pb code the `name` struct first name field tag is the same as the way it's defined im the proto file not lowerCamelCase.

```
type Name struct {
  FirstName string   `protobuf:"bytes,3,opt,name=first_name,json=firstName,proto3" json:"first_name,omitempty"`
}
```

As you can notice the JSON tag is underscored `json:"first_name,omitempty"` this cause failure when I unmarshal the json paylod to struct `Name`.

```
"name": {
  "firstName": "foo"
}
```

The only way to get it to work is re-name the field in the proto file to match the JSON payload like this:

```
message Name {
  firstName = 1;
}
```

Any idea how to get this to work while still keep using the recommended protobuf syntax for naming fields?

Comment: You can try to use JSON payload: `{"name": {"first_name": "foo"}}`.

Comment: Use [the protojson package](https://godoc.org/google.golang.org/protobuf/encoding/protojson): "This package produces a different output than the standard 'encoding/json' package, which does not operate correctly on protocol buffer messages."

Answer (score 0):

IMO. you can `custom serializer`

https://grpc-ecosystem.github.io/grpc-gateway/docs/customizingyourgateway.html

> Using camelCase for JSON The protocol buffer compiler generates
> camelCase JSON tags that can be used with jsonpb package. By default
> jsonpb Marshaller uses OrigName: true which uses the exact case used
> in the proto files. To use camelCase for the JSON representation,
>
> mux :=
> runtime.NewServeMux(runtime.WithMarshalerOption(runtime.MIMEWildcard,
> &runtime.JSONPb{OrigName:false}))

Comment: The latest version of `runtime.JSONPb` (github.com/grpc-ecosystem/grpc-gateway/v2 v2.5.0) does not have `OrigName`. You can however use `UseProtoNames: true`.